# Array.find function does not work in nodejs (works in CLI, not file project)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
let l = [{ id: 12, name: 'f' }, { id: 23, name: 'hhh' }];
console.log(l.find(p => p.id == 23));
```

Upper code works on the command line (cmd->node prompt)

However, if I put into node js code, and run the file. it logs `-1`

My node version: v6.9.5

Answer (score -2):

try running `console.log(process.version)` in both environments.

Comment: they are the same. both: v6.9.5